# Understanding a Natural Isomorphism Induced by Graphs and Categories

Tags: category-theory

In *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, the author states a fundamental connection between graphs and categories:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $G = \{ A {\rightarrow \atop \rightarrow} G\}$ be a small graph. There is a small category $C = C_G$ with $O$ as set of objects and a morphism $P : G \rightarrow UC$ of graphs from $G$ to the underlying graph $UC$ of $C$ with the following property. Given any category $B$ and any morphism $D : G \rightarrow UB$ of graphs, there is a unique functor $D' : C \rightarrow B$ with $(UD') \circ P = D$.

Within this context, the author continues:

> Graphs may be used to describe diagrams. If $G$ is any graph, a *diagram* of the shape $G$ in the category $B$ may be defined to be a morphism $D : G \rightarrow UB$ of graphs. By the theorem, these morphisms $D$ correspond exactly to functors $D' : C_G \rightarrow B$, via the bijection $D' \mapsto D = UD' \circ P$.

Immediately after, the author states:

> This bijection
>
> $$
> \mathbf{Cat}(C_G , B) \cong \mathbf{Grph}(G, UB)
> $$
>
> is natural in $G$ and $B$.

**Question:** I am confused by this statement. What is the precise natural isomorphism being referred to here? Are the functors of the natural isomorphism from $G \times B$ to $\mathbf{Set}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $G$ is a graph, not a category. When 'considering it as a category', we will get exactly $C_G$, which can also be called the *free category* over $G$.

The functors are of the form ${\bf Grph}^{op}\times{\bf Cat}\to{\bf Set}$, acting as follows:
$$\matrix{(G,B)\mapsto {\bf Cat}(C_G,\,B) &|& 
(G,B)\mapsto {\bf Grph}(G,\,UB) \\ 
(\gamma,\beta)\,\mapsto\, \big[f\mapsto \beta\circ f\circ\gamma' \big] &|&
(\gamma,\beta)\,\mapsto\, \big[f\mapsto U\beta\circ f\circ\gamma\big]
}$$
where $\gamma':C_G\to C_{G'}$ denotes the image of the graph morphism $\gamma:G\to G'$ under the free functor, which can be constructed by the theorem.

> $\quad\quad$ by choosing $B=C_{G'}$ and $D=\gamma$

Comment: This is the Hom-Functor on $\mathbf{Grph}^{op} \times \mathbf{Cat} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$, correct?

Comment: Two hom-functors are involved, ${\bf Grph}^{op}\times{\bf Grph}\to{\bf Set}$ and ${\bf Cat}^{op}\times{\bf Cat}\to{\bf Set}$, composed by the adjoint functors $G\mapsto C_G$ and $B\mapsto UB$, on the left and on the right component, respectively. On the other hand, this adjunction can be expressed as *one* **profunctor** ${\bf Grph}^{op}\times{\bf Cat}\to{\bf Set}$.